# rsync without password, none of google (server fault) tutorials worked

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I need to use rsync for a daily backup operation and in the past (on different servers) I managed to just use a rsa key etc, but now none of google (serverfault) tutorials work at all.

It keeps asking me for a password.

I have webmin and ssh/root access to both servers.

My steps:

1. create a key on server 1
2. send `key.pub` to server 2
3. add `key.pub` to `.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. `chmod 700 .ssh/authorized_keys`
5. go back to server 1 and try rsync and it keep asking for password...

rsync command:  `rsync -avz -e ssh file.txt root@server2:/root`

EDIT:
well, I cleaned up everything and this time, instead of inserting a custom name to the key I used the standard one on server1. sent the .pub to server2 and it worked as a charm... So the answer is that server1's ssh wasn't even using the right key...

Comment: does the remote server allow ssh connection with root? have you tried sshing first?

Comment: Did you check the logs on the remote server?

Comment: I'd use 600 for the perms and ensure the .ssh directory has the correct perms as well.  Be aware that on some machines it's not authorized_keys, but could be authorized_keys2 or more likely known_hosts.

Comment: 1-@Migs : Yes, I have root ssh access to both servers, I own both, literally.
2-@Oliver : Yes, and the logs were in debug mode, still, nothing relevant on var/log/auth
3-@FreudianSlip : I tried 600, no success. I will check the known_hosts thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the standard name during key creation. All other steps kept the same and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You may specify what key to use, as explained in my comment on other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check that your new server will allow root logins and accepts public key authentication.

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ensure that

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

and

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

The default for both is yes so unless they are listed and not yes then you're good. If you change either restart sshd.

Check also that the `~/.ssh` directory permissions are 700

Another thing to check is that it's not the local passphrase for the private key it's asking for is it ? If it is you may want to remove the passphrase and then take steps secure the public key by locking down which commands can be run with it.

Comment: PermitRootLogin=yes returns an error:  Bad configuration option: PermitRootLogin (tried with/out equal sign etc)

Permissions checked, all options were checked; next step will be 000, lol

I didn't put any passphrase, that breaks the purpose completely since I need a credential less rsync, for automated backup

Comment: well, I cleaned up everything and this time, instead of inserting a custom name to the key I used the standard one on server1. sent the .pub to server2 and it worked as a charm... how can I give a custom name to a key and make it work?

Comment: You might want to `PermitRootLogin without-password` to be on the safe side (without-password means pubkey-only)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to connect via ssh for the first time. This will prompt you about storing the new server fingerprint on .ssh/known_hosts. Then, once you answered positively, it should connect.

The connection may fail for many many reasons. For example, if you added options for that specific host in `.ssh/config` file, or if your ssh programs do not agree on an authentication schema. In order t better check what happen, you may connect via ssh using option `-v`. This will print a few information on your screen. Post these lines here, please.

Comment: will do that right now...

Comment: well, I cleaned up everything and this time, instead of inserting a custom name to the key I used the standard one on server1. sent the .pub to server2 and it worked as a charm... how can I give a custom name to a key and make it work?

Comment: btw, as already commented on previous answers and question: I have full access with ssh/root on both servers... :-)

Comment: do you mean that you specify, using ssh, "-i keyname" ?

Comment: You may specify options to be passed to ssh from rsync using the `--rsh` argument as in `rsync --rsh="ssh -i keyname -o BatchMode=yes -o Compression=no" other-rsync-args`